# Mixing OOP javascript with jQuery DOM manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking to start developing with javascript jQuery development in a big way.  I recently read "JavaScript: The Good Parts" by [Douglas Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/), and feel well prepared for prototypal based object oriented development.

I'm now trying to figure out how to weave jQuery usage with the patterns Crockford introduced.  I can think of two reasonable approaches:

1. Add methods to DOM objects returned by jQuery (possibly using jQuery's extend method)
2. Add the DOM objects returned by jQuery as properties of domain objects (and vice-versa), and delegate calls appropriately.  This has the benefit of being able to add methods to the domain objects' prototype.

What recommendations do you have for mixing OOP javascript with jQuery DOM manipulation?

Comment: take a look at lightweight clientside MVC like [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) to combine jQuery objects (views) and Javascript Objects (models)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approaches are very interesting. I'll give you my opinion

> 1. Add methods to DOM objects returned by jQuery (possibly using
>      jQuery's extend method)

I think it's a bad practice. Why? you were adding methods to single objects, so those objects don't have a class (well, they may have one, but we're not defining a class method). It would be an object *based* practice, not an object oriented practice.

> 1. Add the DOM objects returned by jQuery as properties of domain objects
>      (and vice-versa), and delegate calls
>      appropriately. This has the benefit of
>      being able to add methods to the
>      domain objects' prototype.

I think this is a very, very good practice, and as you say, we would be adding methods to object prototypes instead of object instances. *That's oop*.

Just a comment, because i think it's a highly frecuent problem. When making jquery plugins, I think it's a good practice to make a class for the plugin, and append the corresponding class instance to the node where it was applied using .data(), so we don't lose a reference to the instance. It's the more *near to OO* practice I think it can be made for plugins.

Hope this helps. Best regards